# How can I dump and decrypt HTTPS traffic from the command line under linux?

Tags: https, wireshark

I have a web application that I need to debug because I suspect that the request send is altered on its way to the server.

I want to dump the HTTPS traffic received on port localhost:443 and decrypt it so I can check the packages.

Obviously I do have the private hey from the server.

Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ssldump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/).(it works on top of libpcap).

```
ssldump -r <File_Name>.pcap -k <Key_File>.key -d host <IP_Address>
```

You specify the following options with the `ssldump` utility:

```
-r: Read data from the <File_Name>.pcap file instead of from the network.
-k: Use <Key_File>.key file as the location for the SSL keyfile.
-d: Display the application data traffic.
```

You may refer the complete example [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116978)

Comment: And how to get that .key file?

Answer (score 2):

You can import the SSL key in wireshark to decrypt https if Wireshark is compiled with SSL decryption support:

http://www.etherlook.com/howto/use-wireshark-to-decrypt-https/

http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

Comment: This is what I am doing now but I came to a very strange problem, I added the .pem key from the server to the Preferences > Protocols > SSL > IP:443:SSL:/path/to/key.pem but the SSL follow stream returns empty. I checked the logs and I see: `ssl_load_key: can't import pem data: Base64 unexpected header error.`